# How can I extract a friendly URL from an EpiServer PageData object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver

Using EpiServer 8.0, we need to get the "friendly" URL from a PageData object within a C# class.  Without converting the URL, internal links look like "localhost/link/[guid].aspx" instead of "localhost/friendly-link".  I've seen online posts that suggest the following:

```
var urlHelper = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlHelper>();
var friendlyUrl = urlHelper.ContentUrl(currentPage.Link);
```

But when I attempt this, Visual Studio returns the following error:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ContentUrl' and no extension method 'ContentUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the code I presently have, without using statements so it's easy to see the namespaces that are being used.

```
var urlHelper = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper>();
var friendlyUrl = urlHelper.ContentUrl(myPage.Link);
```

Are we missing a reference in our project to make ContentUrl work?  Or is there some alternate code we can employ to get a friendly URL from a PageData object?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [UrlResolver](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/8/D4E69E2) class

```
using System.Web.Routing;
using EPiServer.Web.Routing;

public static class PageDataExtensions
{

    public static VirtualPathData FriendlyUrl(this ContentReference contentReference)
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>().GetVirtualPath(contentReference);
        // or use the singleton
        // return UrlResolver.Current.GetVirtualPath(contentReference); 
    }

    public static VirtualPathData FriendlyUrl(this PageData pageData)
    {
        var contentReference = pageData.ContentLink;
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>().GetVirtualPath(contentReference);
        // or use the singleton
        // return UrlResolver.Current.GetVirtualPath(contentReference); 
    }

    public static VirtualPathData FriendlyUrl(this IContent iContent)
    {
        var contentReference = iContent.ContentLink;
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>().GetVirtualPath(contentReference);
        // or use the singleton
        // return UrlResolver.Current.GetVirtualPath(contentReference); 
    }
}
```

This will return a [VirtualPathData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680187) object that have the property [VirtualPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.virtualpathdata.virtualpath)

In your case

```
var friendlyUrl = currentPage.FriendlyUrl().VirtualPath; // using the extensions above
```

would return `friendly-url/whatever/page`

Comment: Thanks for this Eric.

Comment: @KenPalmer You are welcome, updated the sample a bit as well

Answer (score 1):

System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper does not have a ContentUrl method. You're probably thinking about the [UrlExtensions](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/9/770F4B54) class.

UrlExtensions uses [EPiServer.Web.Routing.UrlResolver](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/class-library/?documentId=cms/9/1E774908) internally. You can use the service locator (or constructor injection, preferably) to get an instance of UrlResolver. Then you can do `urlResolver.GetUrl(myPage.ContentLink);`